# Bulma Navbar burger only working on index.html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bulma

I'm making a website with Bulma (and I'm pretty new to Bulma & CSS frameworks) and have imported Bulma.js for my Navbar burger but it only works on the home (index.html) page.

I'm thinking that the reason for this is because on the other pages I load the navbar with

```
$("#nav").load("../extras/nav.html");
```

and import bulma.js normally in the header. I've tried importing it from the nav.html file and putting it in the body. I've also used window.onload in all sorts of ways. I can verify that the bulma.js is loaded as I downloaded and added a console.log and it works.

This loads the nav.html into the div.

```
<div id="nav"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('loading navbar');
    $("#nav").load("../extras/nav.html");
});
```

[This is the full nav.html file](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjjrXm)

And obviously a line linking bulma.js in the head.

The goal is to get the nav burger to work without changing too much of the content (such as linking nav.html) but currently the nav burger does nothing when clicked (except on index.html page which is the same but with the nav.html code hard coded in)

Also, this is my first Stack overflow post (coming from Reddit) so I hope everything is proper and this problem can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are adding the elements after the JS file has loaded, and after the DOM is "ready".  So when the page loads that clickable element does not exist and thus there is nothing attached to that element.

I would suggest one of a few solutions.

1. Simply add your Nav HTML to each page.
2. Add the click behavior for the hamburger menu to your Nav HTML template.  This is from the Bulma documentation.

```
<script>

  $(".navbar-burger").click(function() {

      // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
      $(".navbar-burger").toggleClass("is-active");
      $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("is-active");

  });

</script>
```

3. Use a templatable language like PHP on the backend, where you can add load templates/resources on the server side as opposed to the front end.

Comment: The second one works fantastically. I didn't want to add the exact same nav to each page if I didn't have too and using something like PHP was pretty advanced for a website like this. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I wouldn't have thought of it myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip jquery, and use framework like Vue, here is another solution:

```
<template>

    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
                <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
            </a>

            <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': showBurger}"  @click="showBurger = !showBurger">
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': showBurger}">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                    Home
                </a>

                <a class="navbar-item">
                    Documentation
                </a>

                <a class="navbar-item">
                    Service
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>


</template>

<script>

export default {

    data(){
        return {
            showBurger: false
        }
    }
}

</script>
```